# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>

Tags: c#, .net, linq, generics

I have defined my own model classes `MyModel.Customer`

I'm getting conversion issue in a method where I have used `<T>` instead of direct Model class.

```
public IEnumerable<T> MyMethod<T>() where T : class
        {
            // my method code
        }
```

getting runtime error :

> base = (14,8): error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type
>   `'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<MyModel.Customer>'` to
>   `'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>'`. An explicit conversion
>   exists (are you missing a cast?)

why so ? any clue ?

Comment: Where does this error exactly occur?

Comment: It sounds like your method shouldn't be generic, if you're always going to return a sequence of customers...

Comment: Please post relevant code that actually cause the error.

Comment: The error in the title of this question doesn't match the error message in the body. Which one is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to do smth like this :

```
public static IEnumerable<T> MyMethod<T>() where T : class
{
    // my method code   
    List<Customer> customers = new List<Customer>()
       {
            new Customer(), new Customer(), new Customer()
       };
    return customers;
}
```

It doesn't work this way...

You should cast every element in a collection explicitly.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> MyMethod<T>() where T : class 
{
    List<T> resultList = new List<T>();   
    List<Customer> customers = new List<Customer>()
       {
            new Customer(), new Customer(), new Customer()
       };
    for(int i = 0; i < customer.Count; i++)
       resultList.Add(customers[i] as T);  // attempt to cast here
    return resultList;
}
```